# Calling my return values into main method? genN cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

1. My variable `genN` cannot be resoveled.  Same error for `gen0`.  I'm
   trying to method `nextG` and `gen0`  into my main method.  I tried to
   create the same type of variables and then put my methods into those
   variables.  But I'm getting and error.  I supose I don't understand
   how to get my return values from my methods to get them into my main
   method to run my program.  Any help is appreciated.
2. Errors found:

> Error: gen0 cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> Error: genN cannot beresolved to a variable

```
public class Rule126 {

      public static void main (String args []) {

        final int CELLS = 49; // # cells per row
        final double RADIUS = 0.50; // < 0.5 to leave a border around the cell
    
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(1000,500);
        StdDraw.setXscale(0,CELLS-1);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0,CELLS/2-1);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
           
        int i =0,
        j = 0;
```

This is where my first error occurs :

```
boolean [] generation0;
generation0 = new boolean [i];
generation0 = gen0;  //error
```

This is where my next error occurs :

```
boolean [] nextGeneration;
nextGeneration = new boolean [j];
nextGeneration = nextG (genN); // error
```

This is my next method to get the `nextG` :

```
public static boolean [] nextG (boolean  [] genN, boolean [] gen0){
    
    boolean [] nextG;
    nextG = genN (gen0); // takes genN array puts it in nextG.
    double x = .5,       // spacing of squares on x axis.
    y = 22;       // spacing of squares on y axis.
            
    for(int h =0; h<23; h++) { // creates 22 generations
          nextG = genN (gen0);
          gen0 = genN (gen0);
          y--;    // decreases y after each genertion
          x = .5;  // resets x after each generation
            
    for(int j=0; j<49; j++){ // determines if cell gets filled or unfilled square.
                
        if( gen0 [j] == false){
           StdDraw.square(x, y, .5);
                    
        } 
        else {
           StdDraw.filledSquare(x, y, .5);
                    
        } // if statement
                
        x++; // increases x after each new cell created.
                
                
    } // for loop 2 
    } // for loop 1
         
    return nextG;
} // nextG

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |     Method: gen0
   |
   |    Purpose: creates the first generation
   |
   | Parameters: genN
   |
   |    Returns: The first gen0
   *-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

 public static boolean [] gen0 ()
 {   
     boolean [] gen0;
                 gen0 = new boolean [49];
               
          gen0[23] = true; // sets the the array at 23 to true or alive.
           
           for(int i =0 ; i<49; i++){  // goes through the first generation
               if( gen0 [i] == false){ // all false except gen0[23]
                  StdDraw.square(i+.5, 22, .5);
                          
                  } else {
                  StdDraw.filledSquare(i+.5, 22, .5);
                  } // if statement
           } // for loop
           return gen0;
 }// gen0

   /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |    Method: genN
   |
   |   Purpose: computes Rule 126 for the next generation
   |
   | Parameters: gen0
   |
   |    Returns: boolean values based on rule 126.
   *-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

public static boolean [] genN (boolean [] gen0)
{
    boolean [] genN;
               genN = new boolean [49];  // array of 49 cells
               
    for(int i = 0; i < gen0.length-2; i++){  // computes and applies rule 126
        
        if( gen0 [i]== true && gen0 [i + 1]== true && gen0 [i+2]==true){
            genN[i+1] = false;
        }
       if(gen0 [i] == true && gen0 [i+1] == true && gen0 [i+2] == false){
        genN [i+1] = true;
       }  
       if(gen0 [i] == true && gen0 [i+1] == false && gen0 [i+2] == true){
        genN [i+1] = true;
       }
       if(gen0 [i] == true && gen0 [i+1] == false && gen0 [i+2] == false){
           genN [i+1] = true;}
       if(gen0 [i] == false && gen0 [i+1] == true && gen0 [i+2] == true){
           genN [i+1] = true;}
       if(gen0 [i] == false && gen0 [i+1] == true && gen0 [i+2] == false){
           genN [i+1] = true;}
       if(gen0 [i] == false && gen0 [i+1] == false && gen0 [i+2] == true){
           genN [i+1] = true;}
       if(gen0 [i] ==false && gen0 [i+1] == false && gen0 [i+2] == false){
           genN [i+1] = false;} // last if statement
    } // for loop
    return genN;
} // genN
```

Comment: I think posting the error messages should be helpful.

Comment: did you declare/initialise gen0 and genN in your main() method?

Comment: Also show us where you declare/instantiate the variables `gen0` and `genN` (presumably also `nextG`) as it is hard to understand the scope of your variables in the way you present the code snippets to us.

Comment: @Christian, try using proper IDE (eg intellij) - it will highlight obvious erros

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, it doesn't look like you ever declared gen0 or genN in your main() method.  You put them in the declaration for your NextG function, which looks fine, but in main() you are trying to assign gen0 to generation0, without declaring it, for example:

```
boolean[] gen0;
```

or you could declare and assign it at the same time:

```
boolean[] gen0 = new boolean[7];
```

for example.

In your case though, you create generation0, then assign it a new array, which is fine so far:

```
boolean [] generation0;
generation0 = new boolean [i];
```

Then, you take the same variable you just assigned to a new array, and try to assign it to something main() has never heard of (gen0):

```
generation0 = gen0;
```

What are you trying to do here? This part doesn't make sense logically, as you just assigned that variable in the last line.  The reason the computer doesn't understand it though, is (at least form what you posted), you never declared gen0 anywhere in main.  You declared it in a separate function, but in main(), it doesn't know what that is referring to.

Later, you do the same thing with genN:

```
nextGeneration = nextG (genN);
```

You are trying to pass a variable called "genN" into the nextG function, but main() doesn't know what genN is, so it can't pass that variable into nextG.

Hope this helps.